# .NET 6 Requests taking too long to reach server

Tags: .net, iis, .net-6.0, iis-express

I have a .NET 6 WebAPI that was working perfectly fine until last week in my local environment.

Now when I try to make any request from any source in my localhost, the requests take between 1 and 4 minutes to reach the controller of the WebAPI. When I deploy it to Azure it works perfectly fine, and no other dev seems to be having the same problem.

I'm not sure if this is a known bug of IIS or what's happening, but it looks like nobody else is having this issue, I suspect it has something to do with the connection pooling but I'm not sure how to manage it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of things, decided to delete the whole project/repo from my pc and cloned it again and this solved it for me... I know it's not a solution but it stopped happening.

Comment: Since VS settings are controlling the development/debugging experience, but they are not checked into repos, so like you found out if you start from a clean state many similar issues can be resolved easily. It would be impossible to tell which setting you changed caused the delay due to the settings relevant.

Comment: @LexLi The curious thing about it is that the first thing I tried was deleting the .vs folder containing all the settings for the project and didn't work, I'm not sure if there's a chance the problem was caused due to a specific branch management or something like that in my repo.

Comment: There are more files in the working folder, than merely `.vs` folder. Many `.user` files and files in `obj` folder (and others) can change VS behaviors, which are rarely fully documented anywhere. Thus, starting from a clean working folder seems to be the only way out.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation, it helped me understand a bit more of it